# Asus Win 7 Laptop Wifi shuts off intermittenly

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, laptop

I've been trying to track down the cause of this problem for a while now.  I have an Asus Win 7 (x64) laptop with an Atheros Network Adapter.  The adapter has been turning off intermittently for some reason.  I'll use the laptop with no problems, shutdown, come back the next day and the wifi may or may not be off.  If it's off I have to manually turn it back on.

I've checked the System Event Log and did not notice anything too obvious.  I also checked the power management for the adapter and I **do not** have the “*Allow the computer to  turn off this device to save power*” check box on.   The driver is version `9.2.0.427` and dated `6/21/11`.  I could not find a newer one on the Asus website.

I can't seem to find a consistent pattern to explain what is causing this.  Does anyone have a way (tool?) to track down the cause of this?  Or, can you point me in another direction to look for the cause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of the previous posts I researched resolved the problem for me.  I did, however, finally resolve this on my own.  For an entirely different reason, I was looking at the event log for some debugging info.  I stumbled across several events that were triggered at start up and later repeated several times.  Among those were some Adobe and Google events.  I rescheduled those events, and, now my problem seems to have gone away.  My theory is that those events were somehow conflicting with the WiFi starting up.  I have no solid proof.  I only know that since changing those events, I no longer have the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well... You have two choices to eliminate this problem.  You can roll back to Atheros driver (9.0.0.173) or take a more drastic measure and roll back to Atheros driver 8.0.x.  Rolling back will definitely resolve your connectivity issue.

Comment: Is this a guess? What's the basis for your answer?

Comment: @rrirower - Internet Research! You're welcome.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could point to your findings. That way, if someone else has the same problem, they can benefit also.

Comment: @rrirower - You are correct.  Unfortunately, I did not save the URL's.  Next time I will.

Comment: @rrirower - Of course, you are free not take my suggestion if you feel it's wrong and not backed by proven research :-) - Good luck! Just trying to help...